# select combined with an update, race condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I would like to do something like this

```
begin trans

declare @maxpriceprice int;
Select @maxpriceprice MAX(price) from products where typeId = 5
```

and later on

```
Insert into products (price) values(@maxpriceprice + RAND() * 10)

commit tran
```

It is rather strange but it is strange application.

between the select and insert i cannot afford to havve people inserting stuff into thedatabase.

Would it be ok to do a select max price with (XLOCK) to prevent other people getting max price until i complete my transaction.

Comment: In `MSDN` it mentioned that `XLOCK` Specifies that exclusive locks are to be taken and held until the transaction completes. S0 it should work as expected `Select @maxpriceprice = MAX(price) from products WITH (xLOCK) where typeId = 5`

Answer (score 0):

You never have a race condition in the database if you let the DBMS handle the locking for you. To do that, you have to give it enough information:

```
insert into products (price) 
select MAX(price) + RAND() * 10 
from products where typeId = 5
```

> Would it be ok to do a select max price with (XLOCK)

Basically, no.  You never want to leave a transaction open and hand control back to an application or a user.  You want to get your ducks in a row, and execute your transaction.  If you want to "lock" something (while, say, the user updates the information) you usually resort to an *optimistic concurrency* strategy whereby at time of update you verify that the row has not changed since it was read.  You might want to read up on the `timestamp` datatype, which supports that style.

SQL also defines cursors, row-level locking, and serializable isolation.  Those are all available too in SQL server, at some cost to concurrency.